# sort a webquery result in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a webquery that I call by refreshing the cell where the query starts. something like the following:

```
Sheets(sheetBeingProcessed).Range(queryAdr).QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

I refresh that using vba, one click, my macro goes through all the sheets, refreshes them one by one, each one comes back with different rows of data each days (sometimes 0 rows), that's all acceptable, and all looks good.

Now, I want to sort the results by the "maturity date" column of each sheet. Any idea how I can do that?

The 2 difficulties are, 1 how to tell where the "maturity date" column is, that is rather easy.
The second problem... how can I sort the results I get??

I tried to activate each worksheet and select the range and sort, but that didn't work

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(sortStartAddress).Select
Dim resultRange As Variant

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Set resultRange = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Selection
```

the last line in the below is failing...

I'm sure there must be a cleaner way without flipping between the worksheets activating them and selecting ranges.. which looks ugly... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't *think* you have to activate each sheet in order to sort them.

Also, you should be able to select the entire region by using the `CurrentRegion` option. See if this works for what you are attempting:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(sortStartAddress).Select
Dim resultRange as Range
set resultRange = selection.CurrentRegion.Select
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(sortStartAddress).CurrentRegion.Sort 'add sort options...
```

Comment: Like your answer better than my own.

Comment: ok will have a look tomorrow morning, but that looks promising. thanks

Comment: ok this wasn't enough as I needed to specify the sorting keys, and to retrieve that I needed to get the current region. Paul's answer helped. But thanks anyway, good tip to learn